# Confirm save prompt in internet explorer with Powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

Currently I'm trying to build a extraction tool for Exact Online. What I am trying to do is:

1. Delete the old backup;
2. Create a new backup;
3. Download the backup (*.bak file) and
4. Restore the backup in SQL Server.

All the steps are working for me. But the download script keeps failing because I'm running the Powershell-script from the Windows Task Scheduler. This script is running wheter a my account is logged on or not.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
[string]$divisionURL,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
[string]$AdministrationNumber,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=3)]
[string]$username,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
[string]$password
)

#Add Assembly's
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.VisualBasic"

#Additional variables: do not edit
$submitButtonElementId = "LoginForm_btnSave"
$newFileName = "Backup" + $AdministrationNumber + ".bak"
$backupLocation = "E:\Extract Exact Online\" + $AdministrationNumber
$backupOldName = "E:\Extract Exact Online\"+ $AdministrationNumber + "\Backup.bak"

#Remove current Backup.bak from Downloads
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;
$FileName = "C:\Users\Downloads\Backup.bak"
if (Test-Path $FileName) {
  Remove-Item $FileName
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 4000;
}

#Remove current backup file
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;
$FileName2 = "E:\Extract Exact Online\"+ $AdministrationNumber + "\" + $newFileName
if (Test-Path $FileName2) {
  Remove-Item $FileName2
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 4000;
}

#Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
Import-Module WASP

#Open internet explorer
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.navigate("https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/SysBackup.aspx?Type=D&Division=" + $divisionURL + "&BackupID=1&_Division_=" +$divisionURL); 
$ie.visible = $true;

While ($ie.Busy) { Sleep -m 10 }
    #Set internet explorer as first screen
    $ieProc = Get-Process | ? { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.HWND }
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($ieProc.Id)
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

    #Webpage loading
    start-Sleep -s 20;

    #Log-in
    $ie.Document.getElementById("LoginForm_UserName").value = $username 
    $ie.Document.getElementById("LoginForm_Password").value = $password 
    $ie.Document.getElementById("LoginForm_btnSave").click()

    #Webpage loading
    start-Sleep -s 20;

    #Download ALT+S - Download
    $wshell.SendKeys('%{s}')  

    #Download time
    start-Sleep -s 90;

    #go to login scherm to log off
    $ie.navigate("https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/MenuPortal.aspx?_Division_=" + $divisionURL);

    #Webpage loading
    start-Sleep -s 20;

    #Log off
    $ie.Document.getElementById('LogOff').click()

    #Webpage loading
    start-Sleep -s 20;

    #Close Internet Explorer
    $ie.quit()

#Sleep
start-Sleep -s 20;

#Move backup to new file location
Move-Item $FileName $backupLocation
start-Sleep -s 3;

#Rename Backup.bak into new filename
Rename-Item -Path $backupOldName -NewName $newFileName
start-Sleep -s 3;
```

My problem is that the script does his job, but can not confirm the save button of internet explorer [saveprompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ycFj.png). I make internet explorer the first screen in a active session, and send a ALT+S combination to confirm the download. But when I'm not logged on, the script do not have a active browser to bring in the front to download the file.

I do not have a direct link to the *.bak file. The download starts (when I'm logged on) if I visit a URL like: [https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/docs/SysBackup.aspx?Type=D&Division=123456&BackupID=1&*Division*=123456](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/docs/SysBackup.aspx?Type=D&Division=123456&BackupID=1&_Division_=123456) .

A Invoke-WebRequest (after logging in) like the code below returns me just the HTML code of the page (with a .bak extension).

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/docs/SysBackup.aspx?Type=D&Division=123456&BackupID=1&_Division_=123456" -Outfile "C:\Downloads\Backup.bak"
```

How can I click on the save button in a inactive ineternet explorer session, or download the *.bak file?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use IE instead of another download method like Invoke-WebRequest?

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest is also giving me a html file instead of the *.bak file I expecting. I guess this is because I do not have a direct link to the file.